# Discord.js SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, While trying to launch my discord bot I got this exception:

> /media/ubuntu/EE81-0482/Javascript/Joker
> Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/ClientPresence.js:1 ;�
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

It was working I'd say a minute prior, All I did was exit the bot and relaunch it then I got this error and couldn't find a fix anywhere, Hopefully, someone here can help me.

Nodejs version: v12.22.1

Discordjs Version: 7.18.1

My Code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "USER", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

const prefix = '$';

const fs = require('fs');

const enmap = require('enmap');

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
//client.events = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_SRV, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
}).then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected To The Database.');
}).catch((err) =>{
    console.log(err);
});

const settings = new enmap({
    name: "settings",
    autoFetch: true,
    cloneLevel: "deep",
    fetchAll: true
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I\'m Online.');
});

client.on('message', async message => {

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    if(command === 'ticket'){

        client.commands.get('ticket').execute(message, args);
    }
    else if(command === 'ticket-setup'){

        // ticket-setup #channel

        let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();

        if(!channel) return message.reply("Usage: `!ticket-setup #channel`");

        let sent = await channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Ticket System')
            .setDescription('React To Open A Ticket.')
            .setFooter('Ticket System')
            .setColor('#450045')
        )

        sent.react('')
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}-ticket`, sent.id);

        message.channel.send(`Ticket System Successfully Setup In ${channel}`)
    }
    else if(command === 'close-ticket'){
        if(!message.channel.name.includes('ticket-')) return message.channel.send('This Is Not A Ticket Channel.')
        message.channel.delete();
    }
    else if(command === 'purge'){
        client.commands.get('purge').execute(message, args);
    }
    else if(command === 'help'){
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {

    if(user.partial) await user.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;

    let ticketid = await settings.get(`${reaction.message.guild.id}-ticket`);

    if(!ticketid) return;

    if(reaction.message.id == ticketid && reaction.emoji.name == ''){
        reaction.users.remove(user);

        reaction.message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${user.username}`, {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: user.id,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
                },
                {
                    id: reaction.message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
                }
            ],
            type: 'text', parent: '855516796706619452'
        }).then(async channel => {
            channel.send(`<@${user.id}>`, new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("This Is Your Ticket").setDescription("Please Describe What You Need And A Staff Member Will Be With You Shortly.").setColor("#450045"))
        })
    }
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (client, discord, member) =>{
    const profileModel = require('../../models/profileSchema');

    let profile = await profileModel.create({
        userID: member.id,
        serverID: member.guild.id,
        pounds: 1000,
        bank: 0,
    });
    profile.save();
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Your version of discord.js may have issues with it. Try reinstalling.

Comment: Edit post with your node version and your discord.js version please

Comment: @HellCatVN I've updated it with my version

Comment: Try moving your discord.js to v12 that is too old now

Comment: @HellCatVN I'll try that

Comment: @HellCatVN I couldn't find how to update it and I'm new, Could you tell me? I'm using npm

Comment: You can remove it from `package.json` find `discord.js` then remove that line and `npm install discord.js`

Comment: @HellCatVN Fixed, Thank you :)